# Remove consecutive lines containing the same pattern

Tags: sed, grep

I'd like to create a sed (or equivalent) expression that would remove consecutive lines containing a specific character. For instance, I have a list of IPs followed by a colon. If they contain a value the following line(s) would not contain a colon. If there are consecutive lines with colons, the first should be removed (since they're empty), as so:

```
+159.0.0.0: 
+159.0.0.1: 
+443/tcp open https
+159.0.0.2: 
+159.0.0.3: 
+159.0.0.4: 
+159.0.0.5: 
+80/tcp open http
+443/tcp open https
```

Desired Result:

```
+159.0.0.1: 
+443/tcp open https
+159.0.0.5: 
+80/tcp open http
+443/tcp open https
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/:.*\n.*:/!P;D' file
```

Keep a moving window of two lines and if both lines contain a `:` do not print the first.

Comment: This was the most elegant solution. The only shortcoming is that it doesn't take into consideration the final line having a colon with nothing after. Since this was the most elegant, I'm awarding this as best answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Karimi thank you. May be I have not understood the problem. If I create a file with only the first two lines of the given example and run the above solution, the result is only the second line. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** To check final line is having colon or not made a bit change to code now too as follows.

```
awk '!/:/ && prev{print prev ORS $0;prev="";next} {prev=$0} END{if(prev && prev !~ /:/){print prev}}' Input_file
```

---

---

Completely tested on your provided sample, could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '!/:/ && prev{print prev ORS $0;prev="";next} {prev=$0} END{if(prev){print prev}}' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
!/:/ && prev{
  print prev ORS $0;
  prev="";
  next
}
{
  prev=$0
}
END{
  if(prev){
    print prev}
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too now.

```
awk '
!/:/ && prev{          ##Checking condition here if a line is NOT having colon in it and variable prev is NOT NULL then do following.
  print prev ORS $0;   ##Printing the value of variable named prev ORS(whose default value is new line) and then current line by $0.
  prev="";             ##Nullifying prev variable value here.
  next                 ##Using awk out of the box next keyword which will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  prev=$0              ##Setting value of variable prev to current line here.
}
END{                   ##Starting END section of current code here, which will be executed after Input_file is being read.
  if(prev){            ##Checking if variable prev is NOT NULL, if yes then do following.
    print prev}        ##Printing the value of variable prev here.
}' Input_file          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: +1 for the Excellent line-by-line explanation. Thanks for sharing this alternative. The only shortcoming is that it doesn't take into consideration the final line having a colon with nothing after.

Comment: @Karimi, sure please check my EDIT solution now and let me know on same then it should work?

Answer (score 1):

Another awk:

```
$ awk '/:/ { p = $0 } $0 !~ /:/ {if (p) {print p} print $0; p = ""} ' file
+159.0.0.1:
+443/tcp open https
+159.0.0.5:
+80/tcp open http
+443/tcp open https
```

Comment: This solution also worked for me. I ran this against a large data set and it handled edge cases for colons in the final line. It also removed unexpected blank lines. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

sed is for s/old/new, **THAT IS ALL**. This will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ awk '/:/{s=$0 ORS;next} {print s $0; s=""}' file
+159.0.0.1:
+443/tcp open https
+159.0.0.5:
+80/tcp open http
+443/tcp open https
```

and is trivial to enhance for anything else you might want to do, for example to handle the final line ending in a colon just add an END section to print the last saved colon-ending line, if any:

```
$ cat file
+159.0.0.0:
+159.0.0.1:
+443/tcp open https
+159.0.0.2:
+159.0.0.3:
+159.0.0.4:
+159.0.0.5:
+80/tcp open http
+443/tcp open https
+159.0.0.6:

$ awk '/:/{s=$0 ORS;next} {print s $0; s=""} END{printf "%s", s}' file
+159.0.0.1:
+443/tcp open https
+159.0.0.5:
+80/tcp open http
+443/tcp open https
+159.0.0.6:
```